# Functions passed in as params - access to other params?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following function:

```
function processFiles(path, ext, callback) {
    fs.readdir(path, callback);
}
```

Is it possible for my passed in `callback` function to access its sibling parameter the `ext`? I ask because I am getting an error in Node (using modules) saying:

> ext is not defined

The callback makes use of a `success()` function that sits in the module I have created.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't magically access arguments from other functions, but you could just pass them

```
function processFiles(path, ext, callback) {
    fs.readdir(path, function() {
        callback(ext);
    });
}

processFiles('path/file', extObject, function(ext) {

     // ext is defined

});
```

Comment: Thanks, so the answer is No, I have to explicitly pass it in somehow like you have done.

Comment: Yes, the answer is no, you don't have access to the arguments from `processFiles` in the `callback` function, unless you somehow pass them, and there's many ways to pass something, but the easiest would be to just pass arguments to `callback`, like above.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adeneo's idea, which was upvoted, off course, you can define a variable outside the scope of all your functions, like

```
var myValue;
```

Then you can modify `processFiles`, like so:

```
function processFiles(path, ext, callback) {
    myValue = ext;
    fs.readdir(path, callback);
}
```

and you can use `myValue` in your `callback`.